# Data At every nth Interval Using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am filtering my data between start date and end End date.
What I am trying to do is  I want to filter data between '31-12-2015 11:19:00' And '31-12-2015 11:25:00' with '2'  minutes interval

```
CREATE TABLE table_1
(
  timestamp_col timestamp without time zone,
  value_col integer
);

INSERT INTO table_1(
        timestamp_col, value_col)
VALUES ('2015-12-31 11:19:10', 10),('2015-12-31 11:20:10', 23),
('2015-12-31 11:21:10', 32),('2015-12-31 11:22:10', 43),
('2015-12-31 11:23:10', 55),('2015-12-31 11:24:10', 32),('2015-12-31 11:25:10', 100)
;
```

This is the Query I am using but not getting result as required

```
SELECT timestamp_col, value_col
  FROM table_1
  Where timestamp_col Between '31-12-2015 11:00:00' AND '31-12-2015 12:00:00'
  AND date_part('minutes',timestamp_col)::int % 2 = 0
```

It is resulting data from "2015-12-31 11:20:10" but i want it to start from "2015-12-31 11:19:10" , "2015-12-31 11:21:10" ...... <2 minutes Interval from starting timestamp between the start date and end date>

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

First, use ISO standard date formats:  YYYY-MM-DD:

```
SELECT timestamp_col, value_col
FROM table_1
WHERE timestamp_col Between '2015-12-31 11:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 12:00:00' AND
      date_part('minutes', timestamp_col)::int % 2 = 0;
------^
```

This doesn't affect your results.  But the second condition is limiting the results to even-numbered minutes.  Hence, you cannot get 11:19, because "19" is odd.

If you want the parity based on the first timestamp, you can calculate the minimum timestamp and compare that:

```
SELECT timestamp_col, value_col
FROM (SELECT t1.*, MIN(timestamp_col) OVER () as mintc
      FROM table_1 t1
     ) t1
Where timestamp_col Between '2015-12-31 11:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 12:00:00' AND
      date_part('minutes', timestamp_col)::int % 2 = date_part('minutes', mintc)::int % 2;
```

Comment: No not getting results as required